# Bison -v flag not doing anything

Tags: bison, flags

when I run bison on my .y file, all I get for output if there are any conflicts is something like:

```
Program.y: conflicts: 3 shift/reduce
```

Which if Program.y is more than a handful of lines long is almost completely useless for debugging.  I've hunted around to get bison to say something more:

```
bison Program.y -v
bison Program.y --verbose
bison Program.y --report=state
```

none of which actually do anything more than the original.  Am I missing something?  Do I need something in my bison file like:

```
%allow verbose
```

or something related?  Or this a worse problem with my configuration of bison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of `-v` is not to display something, but to create a `*.output` file, typically `Program.output` in your case.  You might want to read the documentation, http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Understanding.html.